# Connect webservice with android

Tags: android, soap

I would like to connect my android with my own web service with nested  like    wsdl SOAP request 
Using SOAPUI tool i found the method name is login .but unable to pass params user ,pass under Userlogin. how does specifically call the User login in android (Web service).

androidHttpTransport.responseDump returns error as

refer: [androidHttpTransport.responseDump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9CX9.png)

wsdl SOAP request: [SOPA Request WSDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9CX9.png)